# Dynamic javascript function declaration

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, declaration

I'm working on a code where I must pass a different function to some objects.

In this case, I'm trying to pass a different function for the onchange event. So currently what I got is something like this this:

```
var ArrayList; //Contains some data to use with ObjectArray format { n: data }
var ObjectArray; //Contains several objects format Array[n] = Object;
for(var key in ArrayList){
    var doFunction = function() {
        Object[key].doSomething(ArrayList[key]);
    }
    Object[key].onchange = doFunction;
}
```

The problem here I believe is that I'm afraid it will execute the code as it is declared and not with the values of the actual variables.

Is there a way to pass the function with the values as it executes? or will the variables get parsed the way its written?

Comment: In your declaration above, the onchange will trigger the function and not before

Comment: But this is also valid: for(var key in ArrayList){
    Object[key].onchange = function() {
       doSomething(ArrayList[key]);
    }
  } ---- do watch out for closures

Comment: By trigger do you meant that it will execute on that moment or per example, that in doFunction there won't be an Object[key] but rather a Object[0]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the classic function in a loop problem. You need to understand how **closures** work.

Read the "Example 3" part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/352796) carefully. The whole [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/352796) question, too.

Another example that might help understand intuitively:

```
var key = 5;

var onchange = function () {
    console.log(key);
};

onchange(); // 5

key = 10; // the loop reassigns the key on each iteration

onchange(); // 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me understand a little bit. I'm afraid it's not 100% understood, but I know what to avoid now. I'll just need to read all of it slowly.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be done:

```
var ArrayList; //Contains some data to use with ObjectArray format { n: data }
var ObjectArray; //Contains several objects format Array[n] = Object;
for(var key in ArrayList)
{
    (function(key)
    {
        var doFunction = function() 
        {
            Object[key].doSomething(ArrayList[key]);
        }
        Object[key].onchange = doFunction;
    }(key))    
}
```

Comment: Would it work differently if I'd remove the Object[key].onchange = doFunction; and return doFunction instead and add Object[key].onchange = (function (key) { ... })(key) ?

Comment: You could do it this way - (function(key){Object[key].onchange=Object[key].doSomething(ArrayList[key]);}(key))

Comment: Like - Object[key].onchange = (function(key) var do Function = function() { Object[key].doSomething(ArrayList[key]); } return doFunction; }(key));

Comment: No, you cannot do it that way inside a loop or otherwise all the objects will be assigned the same value throughout! And returning a value inside the loop will not only breaks off the loop but completely exits you out from that function